# Aggregating windows into arrays in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data fame like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [4,5,6], "c": [7,8,9]})

a | b | c
1 | 4 | 7
2 | 5 | 8
3 | 6 | 9
```

And I would like to get one like so:

```
a     | b     | c
[1,2] | [4,5] | [7,8]
[2,3] | [5,6] | [8,9]
```

So I have tried the most obvious thing: `df.rolling(2).apply(lambda values: np.array(values))` which unfortunately is not working as `rolling().apply` strictly expects a scalar (float) as a return type.

So I was playing around with comprehensions.

```
window = 2
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [4,5,6], "c": [7,8,9]})
df = pd.DataFrame({column:[df[column].iloc[i-window:i].values for i in range(window, len(df)+1)] for column in df})
```

This is correct but it looks ugly and is really slow. Also it looses the index type which used to be a date (now int). Is there any better, cleaner way?

Comment: well I can still do what I need to do i.e. `df["foo"] = df["a"].apply(dct)` while still having all the filter and select features of a df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be to use `zip` between the values of the columns of the dataframe:

```
df.apply(lambda x: list(zip(x[:-1:], x[1::])),
         raw=True).apply(lambda x: list(map(list, x))
                         ).apply(pd.Series).T

        a       b       c
0  [1, 2]  [4, 5]  [7, 8]
1  [2, 3]  [5, 6]  [8, 9]
```

Comment: a bit more generic and with numpy arrays: `z = df.apply(lambda x: list(zip(*([x[:-y:]] + [x[i::] for i in range(1, y+1)]))), raw=True) \
  .apply(lambda x: list(map(np.array, x))) \
  .apply(pd.Series).T 
  
z["a"].iloc[0].mean()` where `y` is the windows size